# image change after particular time

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview, nstimer

I have three images and 1 imageview , i want to show each image one by one and repeats in imageview after a 3 seconds. Can any one give me some suggestion or link?Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the animation feature of `UIImageView` for this purpose.

```
 // create the view that will execute our animation
 UIImageView *campFireView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];

 // load all the frames of our animation
 campFireView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:   
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage01.png"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage02.png"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage03.png"],
                             nil];

 // all frames will execute in 3 seconds
 campFireView.animationDuration = 3;
 // repeat the annimation forever
 campFireView.animationRepeatCount = 0;
 // start animating
 [campFireView startAnimating];
 //Add imageView to view
 [self.view addSubview:campFireView];
```

Check this [tutorial](http://appsamuck.com/day2.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can use NStimer method to control changes after some interval. Try to work on it.